# Numberformat does not change cell value in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting, string-parsing

I have a range of numbers formatted as text in column A that represent date:

```
02 10 'which means 02 October 
03 11 'which means 03 November
04 12 'which means 04 December
```

What I'm trying to do is to parse this string in order to turn it into a proper date format here is my code:

```
Dim l As Long
Dim s As String
Dim d As Date
Columns("a").NumberFormat = "0000"
l = Range("A3").Value
s = CStr(l)
d = DateSerial(CInt(2017), CInt(Left(s, 2)), CInt(Right(s, 2)))
Range("A19").Value = d
Range("a19").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

The problem that I encounter is when a cell value in column A is 2 10 (second of October) my number-format does force it to become 0210 but the value of the cell itself is still 210 so my string parsing doesn't work how can I bypass this problem?

Comment: Leave it as text and use Split().

Comment: could you please show me the code for that

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Value = DateSerial(2017, CInt(Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A3"))(1)), CInt(Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A3"))(0)))
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function) on the cell's [.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-text-property-excel).

```
Range("A19").Value = dateserial(2017, split(Range("A1").Text, chr(32))(1), split(Range("A1").Text, chr(32))(0))
Range("A19").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: Somehow i get a running error "9" Subscript out of range ;(

Comment: @MehdiFlame then you do not have the space between the numbers like you are showing.

Comment: Step 1 - type `'03 10` into A1. Step 2 - run these two lines of code. Step 3 - `10/03/2017` is in A19.

Comment: You are totally right since the data was extracted through OCR some do have space others not can i do something about it?

Comment: @MehdiFlame when you ask a question it is expected that you would show all possible inputs and desired outputs, not just the ideal cases.  It makes us answer the wrong question.

Comment: maybe `Range("A19").Value = DateSerial(2017, Right(Range("A1").Text, 2), Left(Range("A1").Text, 2))`

Comment: It seems i cant choose @ScottCraner answer as the right one as it answered my original question anyhow ill choose jeeped answer as the right one as it is fairly similar to scott's solution and sorry guys for the inconvenience .